# LibGDX updating a label while a mouse button is being clicked

Tags: java, libgdx, label

I have a float value that is set from 0 to 100, and I want to register a long click and update a `Label` progressivly, so that like every 0.25seconds the label's text will be updated. For now I am using a custom made Label that has a method to update the text displayed.
I tried using touchDown like this:

```
while (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) {
    double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(Button.getText()
            .toString());
    if ((int) currentValue != 0)
        currentValue--;
    Button.updateText(Double.toString(currentValue));
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work, how do I update a label while a button is clicked?

Edit: Most of the code for the ClickListener:

```
        @Override
        public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer,
                Actor fromActor) {
            super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);
            TextButtonStyle style = ButtonLower.getStyle();
            style.font = red;
            ButtonLower.setStyle(style);
        }

        @Override
        public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer,
                Actor toActor) {
            super.exit(event, x, y, pointer, toActor);
            TextButtonStyle style = ButtonLower.getStyle();
            style.font = white;
            ButtonLower.setStyle(style);
        }

        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
            System.out.println(event.toString());
            double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(Button.getText()
                    .toString());
            if ((int) currentValue != 0)
                currentValue--;
            Button.updateText(Double.toString(currentValue));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Buttons.LEFT)) {
                double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(Button.getText()
                        .toString());
                if ((int) currentValue != 0)
                    currentValue--;
                Button.updateText(Double.toString(currentValue));
            }
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
```

Comment: whats the output of your program? is there an error message?

Comment: At the moment it just freezes, even though I am releasing the left mouse button. It doesn't update the label either.

Comment: have you tried replacing the while with an if?

Comment: I need it to update while the button is pressed, not really sure an if would help me here. The code is written in the touchDown method.

Comment: Using an if doesn't work, it merely takes one off, so if for example the setting is 100, and press a button to make it go down, it will take down on the touch down, and on the touch up, in total it will take down 2.

Comment: can you post the rest of the code for this class, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing which of your classes implements your `InputListener`, it's a little hard to tell you exactly what to do to fix your problem. However, in the general sense what you probably want to do is have a boolean flag set to true on your `touchDown` method, set to false on your `touchUp` method, and then in some method that gets called every frame (`act`, `draw`, etc., depending on your implementation), youll want to update your text.

The code would look something like

```
private boolean flag = false;

@Override
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
        int pointer, int button) {
    if (button == Buttons.LEFT) {
        flag = true;    
    }
    //other stuff
    return true; //or whatever you want
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
        int pointer, int button) {
    if (button == Buttons.LEFT) {
        flag = false;    
    }
    //other stuff
    return false; //or whatever you want
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    if (flag) {
        double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(Button.getText()
                    .toString());
            if ((int) currentValue != 0)
                currentValue--;
            Button.updateText(Double.toString(currentValue));
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

depending on your targetted audience, you may also have to deal with pointer id's in some way (this code example wont work if the user clicks on the label with two fingers, then releases one but not the other)